# Sharing image with caption in facebook using facebook share button only shares image

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I am building an application in which user can share an image with a message/caption using the `share button` inside the application which I have implemented from `[facebook docs][1]`. The problem is that the image gets shared but the message/caption doesn't.

The code is given below :

**MainActivity.java**

**(inside `onCreate method`)**

```
shareButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareDialog=new ShareDialog(this);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //selectedContentShare();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked share",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            sharePost(imagePost,temp);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),temp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});
```

Here `imagePost` is the image to be shared and `temp` is the message/caption. I have used a `Toast` message to check whether `temp` is null or not but it is not null.

As specified in the [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) I have implemented the functionality of the `share button`. The code is given below :

**(outside `onCreate method`)**

```
public void sharePost(Bitmap imagePost,String temp){
    SharePhoto photo=new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(imagePost)
            .setCaption(temp)
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent content=new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

Here `imagePost` is the image to be shared and `temp` is the message/caption.

**[Updated]**

The [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) which I followed for posting the image with caption, I followed the same for a `link to a website` with a `quote` and it gets posted, but `image with any texts` doesn't get posted. The code is given below :

```
public void sharePost(){
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setQuote("quote")
                .build();
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain and help me as to why the caption is not being shared

Answer (score 0):

I think `setCaption` might be deprecated.

> > When you implement sharing, your app should not pre-fill any content to be shared. This is inconsistent  with Facebook Platform
> >     Policy, see Facebook Platform Policy, 2.3